# NetworkX read of Shapefile returns empty list of subgraphs

Tags: graph, networkx, shapefile

I have two shapefiles of roads in the city of San Francisco, one obtained via the [US Census](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=Roads) and one via [SFData](https://data.sfgov.org/Government/Bay-Area-Cities-Zipped-Shapefile-Format-/nghj-u9xk/data).

I'd like to use the second one, it seems more filled out.

But when I try to find the connected subgraphs of it, I get an empty list.  While for the Census version I get a healthy list of objects like `<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x11ef99cdb00>`.

I assumed (naively) that the SFData was a completely connected graph, but all the documentation I've read suggests in that case that I'd still return a single-element list.

What am I missing?  How can I get the SF Data into a usable graph?

```
import networkx as nx

#sfdata
g = nx.read_shp('Road files/geo_export_93b884b0-683e-4cbe-bde2-78574254c7f2.shp')
sg = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(g.to_undirected()))

#census
g2 = nx.read_shp('Road files/tl_2016_06075_roads.shp')
sg2 = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(g2.to_undirected()))
```

Comment: I had the a similar issue where I'd read in a shapefile, but get no edges or nodes.  My issue ended up being that the GetGeometryType call returned '3002', which seems to correspond to a specific type of line.  Version 1.11's  read_shp function seems to only accept specific types of geometry (i.e. 0,1).  Maybe try GetGeometryType and see what it returns.  Let me know if you figure something out, I haven't solved this yet.